# Meaning of 'runic dot plots'

Tags: reading-comprehension

> Another Federal Open Market Committee statement, another Jerome Powell press conference, another round of **runic dot plots**, another bout of hyperventilation as markets and the press attempt to make sense of new marching orders from the Federal Reserve.

The original article is [here](https://www.wsj.com/articles/what-the-federal-reserve-told-ftx-victims-fomc-jerome-powell-investments-investors-cryptocurrency-inflation-11671121841?st=ht6h16lc51jumzz&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink).

I know 'rune' means old character or mysterious symbol and 'plot' does conspiracy. Do  'runic dot plots' figuratively mean some attempts hard to understand and evil? If so what does 'dot' mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [dot plot](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/dot-plots.html) is a simple chart for illustrating a data set.  Each item in the data set is represented as a dot, and you can see the frequency as the number of dots in a particular category.

The [federal reserve uses a dot plot](https://www.bankrate.com/banking/federal-reserve/federal-reserve-dot-plot-explained-how-to-read-interest-rates/) to show the distribution of official forecasts for the main short term borrowing rate.

[image]

These are (poetically) described as "runic" meaning "mysterious and hard to interpret".

"Plot" is unrelated to the meaning of "conspiracy". A hyphen would have made clear that this is a "dot-plot" and a type of statistical chart.